# Angular using HttpClient and adding mulitple params to Get

Tags: angular

Using Angular6 here.

My API is called as:

```
    https://localhost:44300/list/pete/id/open
```

In my angular I am calling this API as:

```
  getData(name, id, status): Observable<any[]> {
    // Initialize Params Object
    let params = new HttpParams();

    // Begin assigning parameters
    params = params.append('name', name);
    params = params.append('id', id);
    params = params.append('status', status);

    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(this.url + '/list', {  params: params });
 }
```

The issue is when my UI calls this getData method, the calls that goes to the API is as below (as seen in console):

```
https://localhost:44300/list?name=pete&id=981&status=open
```

This call is not same as per my actual API call. How can I make changes and correctly pass params.

--Updated Code--

```
 getData(name, id, status): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(${ this.url } / list / ${ name } / ${ id } / ${ status });
  }
```

I get these error:

```
Cannot find name $
Expected 1 or 2 arguments, but got 5
The left hand side of arithmetic operation must be of type any, number, bigint, enum type
',' expected
```

Comment: params is for query parameters. Not for path parameters. Just concatenate them to form the final path.

Comment: @JBNizet I understood now that params are for query. But I dont understand how shall I concatenate them. Could you please provide an example. Do I just construct my URL like return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(this.url + '/list' + name + '/' + id + '/' + status);

Comment: Yes. You can also use a template string, using backticks as delimiters: `${this.url}/list/${name}/${id}/${status}`.

Comment: @JBNizet see my updated post the errors I get when I use your code as it is. Looks like I am missing something here?

Comment: The keyword is the [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @jb  when I do the above I see in my console its making call to my api as: localhost:44301/$this.url/list/$%7B%20name%20%7D/…" which errors out because its incorrect

Comment: Post your exact code. You're doing something wrong.

Comment: I resolved it now, I did not had ${} around my this.url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot backticks (`)

```
getData(name, id, status): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(`${this.url}/list/${name}/${id}/${status}`);
}
```

see: [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: sorry when I do the above I see in my console its making call to my api as:  https://localhost:44301/$this.url/list/$%7B%20name%20%7D/$%7B%20id%20%7D/$%7B%20status%7D"  which errors out because its incorrect